# Почему генератор иконок fontello уменьшает толщину линий иконок?

Tags: html, шрифты, вектор, иконки, illustrator

Есть нарисованная в иллюстраторе иконка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу создать семейство шрифтов в [генераторе иконок Fontello](http://fontello.com/), но почему-то он ее искажает и на выходе получаю иконку с тонкими линиями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как добиться изображения точь в точь, а именно в частности жирности линий?

Comment: пора переходить на svg sprite и все будет гуд

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle поясните пожалуйста. как это отразится на кроссбраузерности? поддержка псевдоэлементов предусмотрена?

Comment: смотря поддержка каких браузеров вам нужна

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle кроссбраузерность на сегодня предполагает ie9+ этот сервис? https://iconizr.com/

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle с кроссом - ок, но мне не понятно поддерживают ли эти спрайты `:before` и `:after` - по опыту можете сказать? в документации не увидел, чтобы это было описано

Comment: использовал все было ок